# Want to refresh an image on a wordpress page every 3min

Tags: wordpress

Would like to know how to have an image only auto-refresh every 3 min on a WordPress page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a plugin that adds a Slider to your website...

Comment: jQuery in Posts, Pages, Custom Post Types (WordPress plugin) Thanks QuarK

Answer (score 0):

WordPress loads jQuery so you can use the jQuery load function. Set an id value on the image tag, "myImage" in this example. Place the call in script tags on your page, or in an external javascript file. Using setInterval you can call this code every 180000 milliseconds, which is 3 minutes.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
<script> 
    setInterval( function() { 
        $( '#myImage' ).load( window.location );
    }, 180000 );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setinterval function of jQuery .